# Word for a fictional description used as a substitute?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Is there a word for a fictional but "equivalent" description of a thing, formulated to serve as a conceptual substitute for the thing in order to make a specific point?  For example, while comparing a proposal for Universal Basic Income (UBI) with a proposal for universal free college, I invite you to "think of free college as UBI plus a mandate that the income is spent on college."

The "UBI + mandate" description is equivalent to free college in a similar sense to two different blocks of computer code that "do the same thing."  Minimally, they are equivalent in the sense that the pros/cons of free college should be invariant under this conceptual substitution.  Is there a word for such a fictional description?  I want something to complete the sentence:  "UBI conjoined with the spending mandate is a [insert noun here] for free college."  A compound word or phrase would be acceptable as well.

"Thought experiment" doesn't seem quite right, and I'm looking for something more narrow in meaning than the verb "reframing."  In any case, neither of these words label "UBI + mandate" itself, which is what I want.  **Edit:**  *"Metaphor," "analogy," and "counterpart" are close, but they suggest mere similarity rather than equivalence between source and target.  I wouldn't say two blocks of code which alphabetize a list are merely analogous, for example, as this seems to underappreciate their functional sameness, but I also couldn't call them identical if they're implemented differently.*

Comment: How about "metaphor"?

Comment: My suggestion: *UBI conjoined with the spending mandate is **analogous to** free college.*

Comment: You managed to convey your idea here quite clearly by using the word *equivalent*. Why do you think that you need **another** word?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "counterpart"? *UBI conjoined with the spending mandate is a **counterpart** for free college.*

Answer (score 0):

Fiction is probably not the right word since fiction is almost necessarily known to be false, whereas what you describe seems to be plausibly correct. Mental is probably closer to the right description, since that can be true or false.

More importantly though, what is happening is not merely a substitution but a breaking apart of concepts from something else. As such
I would the separation of one concept from another thing an abstraction, because the concepts are being an abstraction. An American Dictionary of the English Language by Noah Webster defines the word as such:

> 1. The act of separating, or state of being separated.
>
> 2. The operation of the mind when occupied by abstract ideas; as when we contemplate some particular part, or property of a complex object, as separate from the rest. Thus, when the mind considers the branch of a tree by itself, or the color of the leaves, as separate from their size or figure, the act is abstraction so also, when it considers whiteness, softness, virtue, existence, as separate from any particular objects. 
> The power which the understanding has of separating the combinations which are presented to it, is distinguished by logicians, by the name of abstraction.

Granted, Webster's definition is suggestive that it only applies from physical, or concrete if you rahter objects to mental concepts, but the principle operation of this figure of speech is that of separation, and I think the abstraction of more elemental concepts from more complex ones also has good precedent to it.  [The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia in particular seems to have some relevant illustrative quotations](https://books.google.com/books?id=PZ6nlaaBWuwC&pg=PA24&dq=abstraction+locke+century+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC3ZKUlqjjAhVCO30KHV6SBeAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), and I think its application to Lockean philosophy as described on [page 68 of Locke by Samuel C. Rickless](https://books.google.com/books?id=qi8KAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT68&dq=abstraction%20locke&pg=PT68#v=onepage&q&f=false) is of particular interest for demonstrating that.

However, it should be noted that an abstraction does not necessarily lead to a complete set of elements that may be substituted for a more complicated idea.

If you want to refer to the whole set, then another word along a similar train of  thought is **[breakdown](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/breakdown)**. This one seems to be a little more modern, as it is more often used to describe something  which has become broken, but in a more figurative sense it can be used to refer to a whole set of related items which have been broken apart for the purposes of analysis. [The American Heritage Dictionary 5th edition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/breakdown) Breakdown that as meaning:

> 4. An analysis, an outline, or a summary consisting of itemized data or essentials.

When the word breakdown is used it more often refers to a more complete itemized list. For example:

> Here's the breakdown in dollars: base pay $222, flight pay $100, quarters $85, and subsistence $47, for a grand total of $454 per month or $5,448 a year, so 53 percent of my gross income went for a set of wheels.

Applicability of this to concepts more easily comes in the form of the phrasal verb break down, as in "Let's break down that idea", which refers to the simplification of complex concepts:

[National Committee on Boys and Girls Club Work., 1981](https://books.google.com/books?id=nA8hAQAAMAAJ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihmL6rpKjjAhUGsZ4KHd7zBRgQ6AEILTAB)

> The majority of people could improve their eating habits; we need to teach kids the concept of eating right— what to eat and how much to eat.
>
> Q: Let's break down that idea a little. How does a person know what and how much to eat to insure a balanced diet?

I can not read the whole context to be certain, but it seems like what is being requested is a series of instructions that is synonymous with the concept of teaching kids how to eat right.

I am tempted to separate these out into two separate answers, but the reason I am tying them together into one is because they are sometimes used together that show the relationship between the two:

[Innovative Trends in Flipped Teaching and Adaptive Learning](https://books.google.com/books?id=kv2SDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR1&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q&f=false), edited by Sein-Echaluce, María Luisa, Fidalgo-Blanco, Ángel, García-Peñalvo, Francisco José:

> Unit 1 is titled "Basic Concepts", and it has six topics. In the definition of pillar "To Know" we found the verbs Identify, Recognize and Describe, which belong to Bloom's taxonomy level two. In the definition of the pillar "To Know How to Do" we find the verb Determine to be Bloom's level two and the verb Scheme from level four, which is the same level of Comprehend and Aanalyze. In cosnequence, we chose that these belong to the Abstraction and Breakdown skills.

It should also be noted that sometimes the word breakdown is described with the word abstract.

[Safety and Reliability: Proceedings of the ESREL 2003 Conference, Maastricht edited by TIM BEDFORD and P.H.A.J.M. van Gelder](https://books.google.com/books?id=ENxYDxQjMb8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&f=false):

> [The] leading principle of an abstract breakdown level means that objects belonging to the same breakdown level share the same abstract level from the real world.